# Difference between \n and endl?

Tags: c++

As I understand `\n` means a new line and `endl` means end of the line.I have read somewhere that using `endl`(stream manipulator) is advantageous.Which one should be preferred and when?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is that `std::endl` flushes the output buffer, and `'\n'` doesn't. If you don't want the buffer flushed frequently(performance issue) then use `'\n'`

Answer (score 1):

`std::endl` also flushes the stream it's put on, while `'\n'` doesn't.

Depends on what you want, to judge which is better to use.

Answer (score 0):

\n merely ends the line. endl ends the line and also flushes the output stream. endl is advantageous when you explicitly care about flushing your output buffer.